# How to send a new line without using `n `r? without an enter

Tags: variables, autohotkey

i know that n means "ENTER", but when i'm using `n, i dont want to press enter. I just want to put the text in a new line, but what "`n" does, it puts in a new line but it also press enter.. i don't want to press enter...
For example

```
::pergunta::Hello, n How are you? n what are you doing? n bye...
```

How can i fix that issue?

Comment: So you want to use (backtick)n to create new lines, but it is pressing `enter`, which is doing something else?

Comment: Correct, i want to put the text in a new line using `n or something else without pressing the enter key... Because when i use `n it puts in a new line  but it also press enter, to send a message for example

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to determine what keystrokes your application uses for this purpose, and then you can implement that in Autohotkey.

For example, in Excel, multiple lines of text can be typed into a single cell by pressing ALT-ENTER at the end of each line (instead of ENTER).

So, the following AutoHotkey script would work for Excel:

```
:X:pergunta::Send, Hello,!{Enter}How are you?!{Enter}what are you doing?!{Enter}bye...
```

The ":X:" at the beginning means "run a script", which in this case is the "Send" command. The !{Enter} part means ALT-ENTER.

You might also want to use SetKeyDelay to speed up the typing of text:

```
SetKeyDelay, 0
:X:pergunta::Send, Hello,!{Enter}How are you?!{Enter}what are you doing?!{Enter}bye...
```